# how to format a string to date form without using date filter, but by only using js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a input tag assosiated with some date picker plugin.

```
         <input type="text"  ng-model="date"/>//for saving to db

         <input type="text" ng-model="date">   // should be able to see date in formatted form here(coming from db)
```

I want date in formatted form in the second input field . I dont want to use date filter in ui, i want to do it in only js.

Comment: why you don't want to use BUILT-IN filter? Anyway, you can create a custom one

Comment: in input feild im using a plugin so in build filter is not working.

Comment: can you show the full code that you have - with the plugin? coz otherwise it's hard to say what's the problem

Answer (score 0):

i see your using angularjs, (i would use filters..., but if you insist on creating your own logic)

in your controller add a watcher and a formatted variable

```
$scope.formattedDate = '';
$scope.$watch('date', function(newValue, oldValue) { $scope.formattedDate = newValue.format('d/m/Y'); }) // using the format function below (assuming date is a date object)
```

And in your utils.js or where ever:

```
Date.prototype.format = function(format){
    var that = this;

    var month = parseInt(that.getMonth()) + 1;

    format = format.toLowerCase();
    format = format.replace('dd',(((that.getDate().toString().length <= 1)? '0' : '') + parseInt(that.getDate()).toString()));
    format = format.replace('d',parseInt(that.getDate()));
    format = format.replace('mm',(((month.toString().length <= 1)? '0' : '') + month.toString()));
    format = format.replace('m', month);
    format = format.replace('yy',that.getFullYear());
    format = format.replace('y',that.getFullYear());
    format = format.replace('hh',(((that.getHours().toString().length <= 1)? '0' : '') + (that.getHours()).toString()));
    format = format.replace('h',parseInt(that.getHours()));
    format = format.replace('ii',(((that.getMinutes().toString().length <= 1)? '0' : '') + (that.getMinutes()).toString()));
    format = format.replace('i',parseInt(that.getMinutes()));
    format = format.replace('s',parseInt(that.getSeconds()));

    return format;
};
```

and you can display formattedDate to the user

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using a filter in the controller, not in the template:

```
app.controller('test', function myCtrl($scope, $filter){
  //other controller code..

  //val - value to format
  $scope.date = $filter('date')(val,'dd/mm/yyyy'); //for example
})
```